# IEnumerable to List

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, generic-list

Why IEnumerable.ToList() won't work if like:

```
 var _listReleases= new List<string>;
_listReleases.Add("C#")
_listReleases.Add("Javascript");
_listReleases.Add("Python");

 IEnumerable sortedItems = _listReleases.OrderBy(x => x);
_listReleases.Clear();
_listReleases.AddRange(sortedItems); // won't work
_listReleases.AddRange(sortedItems.ToList()); // won't work
```

### Note: _listRelealse will be null

Comment: Note that the `List` object has a built-in `Sort()` function, if it'd be easier to use that instead.

Comment: @AndrewArnold yeah I know, I was just curios since the AddRange take IEnumerable as parameter.

Comment: You should always define "won't work".  Does it mean an exception, an error message, an improper result, etc.

Comment: Short explanation: The `OrderBy` Linq extension is **lazy** and won't traverse the list until it is actually forced to do so. The list is cleared *before* the `sortedItems` is traversed. Could be fixed if `.OrderBy(x => x)` is changed to `.OrderBy(x => x).ToList()` which will force immediate enumeration of the list before it is cleared. But a better solution is in @AndrewArnold's comment. Either call `.Sort()` on the original list, or copy the list to a new list and call `.Sort()` on that (if you need the old list still).

Comment: After 6 years I now laugh that I once asked this "stupid" question 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because of this line:

```
_listReleases.Clear();
```

First of all, `_listReleases` is *not* null at this point. It's merely *empty*, which is a completely different thing.

But to explain why this doesn't work as you expect: the `IEnumerable` interface type does *not* actually allocate or reserve storage for anything. It represents an object that you can use with a `foreach` loop, and nothing more. It does not actually need to store the items in the collection itself.

Sometimes, an IEnumerable reference *does* have those items in the same object, but it doesn't have to. That's what's going on here. The `OrderBy()` extension method only creates an object that knows how to look at the original list and return the items in a specific order. But this does not have storage for those items. It still depends on it's original data source.

The best solution for this situation is to stop using the `_listReleases` variable at this point, and instead just use the `sortedItems` variable. As long the former is not garabage collected, the latter will do what you need. But if you really want the `_listReleases` variable, you can do it like this:

```
_listReleases = sortedItems.ToList();
```

Now back to IEnumerables. There are some nice benefits to this property of not requiring immediate storage of the items themselves, and merely abstracting the ability to iterate over a collection:

- Lazy Evaluation - That the work required to produce those items is not done until called for (and often, that means it won't need to be done all all, greatly improving performance).
- Composition - An IEnumerable object can be modified during a program to incorprate new sets of rules or operations into the final result. This reduces program complexity and improves maintainability by allowing you to break apart a complex set of sorting or filtering requirements into it's component parts. This also makes it much easier to build a program where these rules can be easily determined by the user at run time, instead of in advance by the programmer at compile time.
- Memory Efficiency - An IEnumerable makes it possible to iterate collections of data from sources such as a database in ways that only need to keep the current record loaded into memory at any given time. This feature can also be used to create *unbounded collections*: sets of items that may stretch on to infinity. You can build an IEnumerable with the BigInteger type to calculate the next prime on to infinity, if asked for. Moreover, you could use that collection in a useful way without crashing or hanging the program by combining this with the composition feature, so the program will know when to stop.

Comment: yeah but is if I remove Clear(), the items will sorted and duplicated in _listReleases @Joel

Answer (score 3):

LINQ is lazily evaluated. When you run this line:

```
IEnumerable sortedItems = _listReleases.OrderBy(x => x);
```

You aren't actually ordering the items right then and there. Instead you're building an enumerable that will, when enumerated, return the objects *that are currently* in `_listReleases` in order. So when you `Clear()` the list, it no longer has any items to order.

You need to force it to evaluate *before* you clear `_listReleases`. An easy way to do this is to add a [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) call. Also, the type `IEnumerable` isn't compatible with [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) won't accept it. You can just use `var` to implicitly type it to `List<string>`, which will work because `List<T> : IEnumerable<T>` (it implements the interface).

```
var sortedItems = _listReleases.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
_listReleases.Clear();
_listReleases.AddRange(sortedItems);
```

You should also note that methods like `ToList()` are extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IEnumerable`, so `((IEnumerable)something).ToList()` won't work. Unlike, say, Java, `Something<T>` and `Something` are completely distinct types in C#.

Comment: The fact that LINQ is lazy doesn't matter.  AddRange accepts an IEnumerable<T>, not a List<T>, so any object that implements IEnumerable<T> will work.

Comment: @NathanA if you just fix the type, `_listReleases` is empty in the end, because LINQ is lazy. Both are problems, maybe he only noticed one or the other. Maybe his code actually has a proper type there (his syntax has some errors, maybe copy related). In any case, the lazy evaluation is relevant.

Comment: @NathanA The fact that execution is deferred most certainly matters.  it causes his program, as written to not function properly.  Not functioning properly is relevant.

Comment: @DStanley Well, it's not *exactly* the problem.  The OP's code, as is doesn't even compile.  It is *half* of the problem.  Of course, Tim addresses both halfs of the problem in his answer.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I did miss one pivotal issue.  I failed to see that sortedItems was based on the original list. I was simply basing this on a compile error.  Sorry, you are right regarding the Lazy execution.

Comment: I think this still misunderstands what's going on. It's not "lazy execution" that's the problem. The problem is that the _sortedList_ variable still depends on the items in the original list. This is a subtle but real difference from lazy execution. IEnumerable could be implemented such that it runs right away (not lazy) to produce a list of indexes or object references, and the problem here would still remain.